# Why aren't the elements or the background color showing on my Tkinter Toplevel window?

Tags: python, tkinter, window, toplevel

I need to get the "encryption_window" in the code shown to show the colored background and the elements added to it. I open a home window and then click on the "Encrypt" button, but no matter what I do, it always shows a blank, white screen! I have tried everything but I still can't find a solution! I will take any help I can get, so don't hesitate to add in a solution! Can someone show me how to fix this problem, please? Thanks in advance! (PS: The code is in Python!)

```
from tkinter import *
from simplecrypt import encrypt, decrypt
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
import os

master_window=Tk()

def goToHome():
    global home_window
    global encryption_window
    global decryption_window

    encryption_window.withdraw()
    encryption_window.grab_release()
    decryption_window.withdraw()
    decryption_window.grab_release()
    home_window.deiconify()
    home_window.grab_set()
    
def goToEncryptionWindow():
    global home_window
    global encryption_window
    
    home_window.withdraw()
    home_window.grab_release()
    encryption_window.deiconify()
    encryption_window.grab_release()

def goToDecryptionWindow():
    global home_window
    global decryption_window
    
    home_window.withdraw()
    home_window.grab_release()
    decryption_window.deiconify()
    decryption_window.grab_release()

home_window=Toplevel(master_window)

home_window.title('Okoye File Crypter - Home')
home_window.wm_geometry('800x800')
home_window.resizable(False, False)
home_window.config(bg='#88b3a1')
home_window.grab_set()

main_label=Label(home_window, text='Okoye File Crypter', font=('Arial', 20, 'bold', 'italic'))
encrypt_file_button=Button(home_window, text='Encrypt File', bg='#d6e80e', command=goToEncryptionWindow)
decrypt_file_button=Button(home_window, text='Decrypt File', bg='#d6e80e', command=goToDecryptionWindow)

main_label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.2, anchor=CENTER)
encrypt_file_button.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
decrypt_file_button.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

encryption_window=Toplevel(master_window)

encryption_window.title('Okoye File Crypter - Encryption')
encryption_window.wm_geometry('800x800')
encryption_window.resizable(False, False)
encryption_window.config(bg='#88b3a1')
encryption_window.withdraw()

info_label=Label(encryption_window, text='File Name:')
file_name_entry=Entry(encryption_window)
create_file_button=Button(encryption_window, text='Create File', bg='#d6e80e')
home_button=Button(encryption_window, text='Home', bg='#d6e80e', command=goToHome)
file_textfield=Text(encryption_window, width=500, height=500)

info_label.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.2, anchor=CENTER)
file_name_entry.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.2, anchor=CENTER)
create_file_button.place(relx=0.6, rely=0.2, anchor=CENTER)
home_button.place(relx=0.8, rely=0.2, anchor=CENTER)
file_textfield.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

decryption_window=Toplevel(master_window)

decryption_window.title('Okoye File Crypter - Decryption')
decryption_window.wm_geometry('800x800')
decryption_window.resizable(False, False)
decryption_window.config(bg='#88b3a1')
decryption_window.withdraw()

home_window.grab_set()
master_window.withdraw()
master_window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the window is blank is because the extremely large textfield is blocking the elements. I didn't realize this at first, which is why I am answering my own question.
-WillTechX20